performance using python3/pandas to read .ods (opendocument spreadsheet)file
Environment:

  inside docker container in WSL2/Ubuntu22.04
  python 3.12
  pandas 2.2.2
  odfpy 1.4.1
  openpyxl 3.1.3
  
The .ods file I have on disk is 6.8MB (two sheets, one sheet has 16,000 rows, the other has 74,000 rows). I can open this file in MS excel in no time.
I have the following code to read this file (first read it into a bytes variable):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    excel = ExcelFile(BytesIO(file_content), engine="odf")
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    data = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(file_content), engine="odf")
    t3 = time.perf_counter()

the following is the value of t1, t2 and t3 after the file content is read into excel and data:

t1: 366108.7721855
t2: 366606.7265884
t3: 367100.7166519

It takes about 10 minutes to read the data as Excel or pandas dataframe.
Anywhere I can tune to improve the reading performance?
